Global Fault Handling in MassTransit
I want to create a global way to handle errors. My application has it's own internal error handling pattern and I need a single place to dispatch error messages to it.
I can't use IConsumer<Fault<MyMessage>> because I need the actual exception, not the ExceptionInfo object.
I'm trying a Filter that looks like this:
public class ExceptionLoggerFilter<T>(IMediator mediator) : IFilter<ConsumeContext<T>>
    where T : class
{
    public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
    { }

    public async Task Send(ConsumeContext<T> context, IPipe<ConsumeContext<T>> next)
    {
        try
        {
            await next.Send(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var reqType = context.Message.GetType();
            var errorReqType = typeof(FaultRequest<>).MakeGenericType(reqType);
            var errorReq = Activator.CreateInstance(errorReqType, context.Message, ex);
                                                                                                     
            await mediator.Send(errorReq, context.CancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            
            throw;
        }
    }
}

This works, but it happens on every delivery. Is there a way to check and see if the message has been faulted in the catch? Is there a better way to globally catch faults and still have access to original exception object?
EDIT 1:
Based on Chris Patterson's response, I tried rearranging the order of my setup.
mt.UsingAmazonSqs((ctx, cfg) =>
  {
    cfg.UseExceptionHandlerFilter(ctx);
    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(ctx);
    cfg.UseMessageScope(ctx);
  });

I'm using a Consumer definition to setup the retry
public class CreateItemDefinition : ConsumerDefinition<CreateItemConsumer>
{
    protected override void ConfigureConsumer(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator, IConsumerConfigurator<CreateItemConsumer> consumerConfigurator,
        IRegistrationContext context)
    {
        endpointConfigurator.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(ExceptionHandlerFilter<>), context);
        endpointConfigurator.UseMessageRetry(x => x.Immediate(3));
        
        base.ConfigureConsumer(endpointConfigurator, consumerConfigurator, context);
    }
}

With both of these setups, the exception filter is still being called on every redelivery. I guess I'm not understanding what is meant by changing the filter registration order.

Using a middleware filter is the way to do it. Not sure what you mean by it happens on every delivery.

I should have said on every redelivery. The filter is triggered every time the consumer is called, whether it's the first failure or the last failure right before it gets faulted. I was hoping there was some way of knowing if the message was faulted from inside the filter.

Then change the filter registration order so your filter is before the retry filter.

I posted more details about how I tried to implement your suggestion, but I think I'm not understanding something
